# How can I switch the language of TextToSpeech between American English and British English?

Tags: java, android, locale, text-to-speech

I am building a text to speech app. In the app, the user can select whether they want to use American English or British English. So I created a `UserSettings` class that fetches some data from Shared Preferences.

`UserSettings` has a method called `getPrefTTS` which returns a `TextToSpeech` configured to the user's preferences (pitch, rate, and voice). And this is the class:

```
public final class UserSettings {
    private  UserSettings () {}

    private static final String SP_KEY_RATE = "rate";
    private static final String SP_KEY_PITCH = "pitch";
    private static final String SP_KEY_VOICE = "voice";

    public static String getPrefVoice(Context c) {
        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences (c);
        return sp.getString (SP_KEY_VOICE, "GB");
    }

    //irrelevant
    public static float getPrefRate(Context c) {
        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences (c);
        return sp.getFloat (SP_KEY_RATE, 1.0f);
    }

    //irrelevant
    public static float getPrefPitch(Context c) {
        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences (c);
        return sp.getFloat (SP_KEY_PITCH, 1.0f);
    }

    public static TextToSpeech getPrefTTS(Context c) {
        TextToSpeech tts = new TextToSpeech (c, null);
        tts.setLanguage (new Locale ("en", getPrefVoice (c)));
        tts.setPitch (getPrefPitch (c));
        tts.setSpeechRate (getPrefRate (c));

        return tts;
    }
}
```

As you can see, for the `setLanguage` method, I pass in the country that is stored in SharedPReferences. This will either be `GB` or `US`.

Because I haven't put anything into SharedPreferences yet, a default value of `GB` is used.

But when I run the app, a Chinese voice speaks the text out loud, in pinyin! I think this is because my device's language is set to Chinese. But that isn't right! I set the language explicitly to English!

So I changed the `getPrefTTS` method to this to check the result of the `setLanguage` call.

```
public static TextToSpeech getPrefTTS(Context c) {
    TextToSpeech tts = new TextToSpeech (c, null);
    int result = tts.setLanguage (new Locale ("en", getPrefVoice (c)));
    tts.setPitch (getPrefPitch (c));
    tts.setSpeechRate (getPrefRate (c));

    switch (result) {
        case TextToSpeech.LANG_AVAILABLE:
            Toast.makeText (c, "Language Available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show ();
            break;
        case TextToSpeech.LANG_COUNTRY_AVAILABLE:
            Toast.makeText (c, "Country Available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show ();
            break;
        case TextToSpeech.LANG_COUNTRY_VAR_AVAILABLE:
            Toast.makeText (c, "Country Variable Available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show ();
            break;
        case TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA:
            Toast.makeText (c, "Missing Data", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show ();
            break;
        case TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED:
            Toast.makeText (c, "Language Not Supported", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show ();
            break;
    }

    return tts;
}
```

And "Language Not Supported" shows up in the toast.

I think this is because `GB` is not a valid country code, so I tried `UK` and `US` but they all shows `Language Not Supported`!

What should I use to create a locale of UK and US?

P.S. I know there are constants in the `Locale` class, but I want to know what exactly am I doing wrong. My code seems very reasonable.

EDIT:

I decided to use the constants defined in `Locale` (`UK` and `US`) but it still says "Language Not Supported"! What is happening? Is it because of my device?

Comment: take a look at this http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2009/09/introduction-to-text-to-speech-in.html

Comment: @SmashCode I did what the post says but it still uses the device's language (Chinese) to speak the words. But what's more interesting is that when I change the device's language to English, it speaks English! I think there must be something wrong with my code. It is not a problem with the device's own TTS resoures. Do you know why this happens?

Comment: In phone you can only select 1 language to convert text to speech then why not try in your code to change it internally like switching languages on phone rather than in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you choose correct locale code: American English is "en-US", and British English is "en-GB", but your tts instance wasn't connected to TTS service.

Why did you miss `OnInitListener`? This listener will be connect to TTS service of your device system. Try this one:

```
    private static TextToSpeech tts;
    public static TextToSpeech getPrefTTS(Context c) {
        tts = new TextToSpeech(c, ttsInit);
//        tts = new TextToSpeech(c, ttsInit, "specific.tts.package.name.that.you.want.to.use");
    }

    private static TextToSpeech.OnInitListener ttsInit = new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInit(int status) {
            if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
                int result = tts.setLanguage(new Locale("en", getPrefVoice(c)));
                tts.setPitch(getPrefPitch(c));
                tts.setSpeechRate(getPrefRate(c));

                switch (result) {
                    case TextToSpeech.LANG_AVAILABLE:
                        Toast.makeText(c, "Language Available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;
                    case TextToSpeech.LANG_COUNTRY_AVAILABLE:
                        Toast.makeText(c, "Country Available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;
                    case TextToSpeech.LANG_COUNTRY_VAR_AVAILABLE:
                        Toast.makeText(c, "Country Variable Available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;
                    case TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA:
                        Toast.makeText(c, "Missing Data", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;
                    case TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED:
                        Toast.makeText(c, "Language Not Supported", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

Also, `OnInitListener` is operated asynchronously. So you can handle your tts instance after `OnInitListener` is done.

**Tip:** Following `Locale` reference page, locale code consists of language code as defined by `ISO 639-1`, and country code as defined by `ISO 3166-1`.

See this page for more detail: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html